# Video as background in html

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my code I have mentioned this - overflow: hidden in the css but still my video is not shown below the text.I have mentioned the following in my css :

```
fullscreen-bg {
               top: 0;
               right: 0;
               bottom: 0;
               left: 0;
               overflow:hidden;
               `enter code here`z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
                       position: absolute;
                       top: 0;
                       left: 0;
                       width: 100%;
                       height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: share the html also..or possible then share live link/demo or jsfiddle..thanx

Comment: Yes, please share the HTML version and possibly the video background that you are trying to use in a code playground like jsfilddle..

Comment: HTML  -  <div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFumz1WNq4k.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

Comment: I am using this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFumz1WNq4k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't written by me but it should give you a rough idea how to do it,

```
video { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 background: url('//demosthenes.info/assets/images/polina.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}
.stopfade { 
   opacity: .5;
}
```

source:

https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK

Comment: Is it required to use java script for this?